# Prestashop 1.7.2.0 display currency symbol before price on home page

Tags: php, prestashop

I want to change `100 $` to `$ 100` for the products list on the home page in Prestashop 1.7.2.0.

I edited the file from the path `Translations/cldr/main-es-ES-numbers` as follows:

```
"accounting":"#,##0\u00a4\u00a0","standard":"#,##0\u00a4\u00a0"
```

to

```
"accounting":"\u00a4#,##0.00;(\u00a4#,##0.00)","standard":"\u00a4#,##0.00",
```

But it works well except for the home page

Comment: did you try clearing the cache? The prices on the home page are probably displayed by a module, modules ignore the "Clear cache everytime something has been modified" setting in `Advanced Parameters/Performance`

Comment: @defuzed do I have to clear the cache from the server side or the client side?

Comment: try pressing the "clear cache" button at the top right of `Advanced Parameters/Performance` this should clear the module cache

Comment: @defuzed awesome! I can't believe it was that easy!

Comment: haha glad i could help, yeah that behaviour tricked me more than once too, i'll post this as an answer then

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the prestashop cache by clicking "**Clear Cache**" at the top right of `Advanced Parameters / Performance` should do the trick.

Prices and other product related information on the index page of prestashops are ususally cached by the `homefeatured`or other modules. Since modules ignore the performance setting of "clear cache everytime something has been modified", the cache needs to be cleared manually.

Answer (score -1):

Easy to change currency position after and before price with language and change symbol

This module is very good:
https://addons.prestashop.com/en/international-localization/47741-change-currency-position-and-symbol.html